# Is CoCreateInstance using CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER enough to ensure that all the applications will share the COM object instance?

Tags: c++, com, interop

Is CoCreateInstance using CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER enough to ensure that all the applications will use the same instance of the COM object that's loaded during the first CoCreateInstance?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is up to the server to decide, the client has no say over this.

The server uses the [REGCLS enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when it registers its class factories.  With REGCLS_SINGLEUSE, the next CoCreateInstance() call in the client will start another server.  You want REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE.

Answer (score 2):

No, each call to CoCreateInstance will create a new object.

If you want every process to share the same object you'll have to create another class that acts as the factory for the object you want to share.

The other way to get all clients to share the same object is to make your object a proxy object that defers to a singleton within the server EXE.

Comment: Can I use DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON for this?